# Need help on displaying readable date using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, date

I'm new to javascript and I've got this problem of showing dates.

I would like to display a readable date formatted like `MM-DD-YYYY`, but everytime I try to load the page, I always get an ASP format date.

Someone gave this code and I tried to use it on my project, yet, I still get the wrong format of date with this kind of error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'formatDate' of undefined`.

What's wrong with this code?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var date = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', new Date($("#dateOfBirth").val()));
$("#dateOfBirth").val(date);
});
```

I'm using C# MVC.

Comment: Are you using `<input type="date" />`? If so, you must use `YYYY-MM-DD` format for the value.

Answer (score 0):

Might give this a try (assuming you're using jQuery... If I'm way off, I apologize):

```
// You might not need the next two lines...
// And if not, just delete them as well as the last line
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dateOfBirth").datepicker();
    $("#dateOfBirth").datepicker("dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd");
  });
});
```